# Get value from other selectOneMenu from ajax in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need get value from selectOneMenu to other selectOneMenu with ajax.

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{solicitudBean.solicitud.mot_id}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudBean.selectmotivosolicitud}" var="mtv"  itemLabel="#{mtv.mot_nombremotivo}" itemValue="#{mtv.mot_id}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="usuario" value="#{solicitudBean.solicitud.usu_idempleado}"  required="true" requiredMessage=" El Usuario no puede estar vacío"  disabled="#{solicitudBean.modificarver==1?'false':'true'}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione Usuario" itemValue="" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{solicitudBean.selectItems}" />
        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{solicitudBean.cargarDatos(event,solicitudBean.solicitud.mot_id)}" update="rowitemtable" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Where cargarDatos(event,solicitudBean.solicitud.mot_id) not send value, code Bean is:

```
public void cargarDatos(AjaxBehaviorEvent event,int motivo) throws Exception {
    int valor = solicitud.getUsu_idempleado();
    itemsSelect = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    ush_id = valor;
    //I need value from motivo
}
```

Please Help